# MTM With Visual Studio 2012 - Can't see Web Access with update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

I was watching an MTM course on pluralsight: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/transcript/microsoft-test-manager-2012

and in the last module, the following is said:

> Finally, I'm going to show you the new browser-based testing feature
>   introduced with TFS 2012 Update 2.

And later on:

> You can access the web base test case management interface from MTM by
>   clicking on this icon, which is available on the Plan section. You
>   must have Update 2 or above to see this icon

As said before, I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4, but I'm not able to see that icon.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not about the Visual Studio version. What's the version of your TFS server?

Comment: It is a 2012 TFS, specifically: 
Edition: Team Foundation Server| 
License Type: MSDN| 
Product Version: 11.0.50727.1|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TFS server is still at RTM ([according to this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have.aspx)). You need to upgrade your TFS server to at least update 2 (which currently basically means you need to upgrade to to TFS 2012 update 4) in order to get that functionality.